# Bloomberg functions explore into .Net application

Tags: .net, bloomberg

I am facing few issues with requesting to Bloomberg using Open API (.Net platform) feature. Am just converting the excel functions into application. Please see my code below.

Existing excel request

=BDP(A6,col1:val1,col2:val2)

? how to send request for the above?

=BDP($A7, CORR_COEF , BETA_RAW_OVERRIDABLE, CIU Equity, CORR_COEF: BETA_OVERRIDE_START_DT,Date1:Date2,"BETA_OVERRIDE_PERIOD=d")

? how to send request for the above?

=BDS(B1,"TOP_MUTUAL_FUND_HOLDINGS","EndCol=2","StartCol=2","cols=1;rows=10")

```
    Request request = clsConnection.stRefDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
    Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
    Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
    securities.AppendValue("AAA Equity");
    fields.AppendValue("TOP_MUTUAL_FUND_HOLDINGS");
    AddOverride(request, "EndCol", "2");
    AddOverride(request, "StartCol", "2");
    AddOverride(request, "cols", "1");
    AddOverride(request, "rows", "10");
```

Could you please help me to correct the mistake in above code?

---

=BDH(A9,"CORR_COEF",columnA ,columnB ,"BETA_CALC_INTERVAL_OVERRIDE=1y","BETA_OVERRIDE_PERIOD=d","DTS=h","BETA_OVERRIDE_REL_INDEX=AA Index")

```
    Request request = clsConnection.stRefDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
    Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
    Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
    securities.AppendValue("AAA Equity");
    fields.AppendValue("CORR_COEF");
    AddOverride(request,"BETA_CALC_INTERVAL_OVERRIDE", "1y");
    AddOverride(request, "BETA_OVERRIDE_PERIOD", "d");
    AddOverride(request, "DTS", "h");
    AddOverride(request, "BETA_OVERRIDE_REL_INDEX", "AAIndex");


    private void AddOverride(Request request, string fieldId, string fieldValue)
    {
        var override1 = request["overrides"].AppendElement();
        override1.SetElement("fieldId", fieldId);
        override1.SetElement("value", fieldValue);
    }
```

Could you please help me to correct the mistake in above code?